# Calculus of variations ? electrostatic energy problem.

Tags: calculus-of-variations, electromagnetism

> What is the maximum self-energy of an electrostatic distribution subject to the constraints that:
>
> 1. the total charge is $1$; and
> 2. the areal charge density anywhere is either $1$ or $0$.

**How can I formulate this problem in calculus of variations?**

I came up with this problem because I was calculating self-energies of a planar hexagon and noticed it is less than the energy of a round disk of same area, and physically it is reasonable that the disk requires more energy to put together. However I want to know if I can solve this with calculus of variations.

I’d try to use

$$E = \iint {\rho(x) \, \rho(y) \over \lvert x-y\rvert}\, dx\,dy + \int \bigl[ \lambda(x)\, \rho(x) \, (1-\rho(x))  +\mu \, \rho(x)\bigr]\, dx$$

Variation with $\rho$ gives

$$2 \int {\rho(y)\over \lvert x-y\rvert} \,dy + \mu + \lambda(x) \,\bigl[1 - 2 \,\rho(x)\bigr] = 0$$

Let $U(x)$ be the first term, then

$$\rho(x) = 0 \implies U(x) = -\mu - \lambda(x)$$
$$\rho(x) = 1 \implies U(x) = -\mu + \lambda(x)$$

This is where I am now.

Comment: Welcome to MathStackExchange, it is advisable that you provide a bit of context to your question (did you come up with it? Is it a homework question? What kind of course/level are you taking?) It is also recommended to show some work or explain with your word your difficulties. Normally this means showing your attempt to solve this question (note that you can edit your post). Such modifications would be helpful for anyone attempting to answer.

Comment: I've edited it. However I think my approach using rho(x) and the constraints would mean that any variation in rho would not be infinitesimal, and I'm not sure if calculus of variations is applicable this way.

Comment: Are you working on a plane? A line? A volume? In other words, are $x$ and $y$ real scalars or vectors? Also note you can write math in these comments like $\rho$.

Comment: Nice job with your edits! This is a very good debut on our site $\ddot\smile$ I made some aesthetic edits to your post and also attempted to answer one of @Mefitico’s questions by specifying *areal* charge density. Could you make sure everything looks alright?

Comment: I'm also wondering that if $\rho$ is an areal charge density function, perhaps we should write $\rho(x,y)$ instead of $\rho(x)$ and $\rho(y)$.

Comment: @Mefitico I'm working on a plane, however I think it doesn't matter if it's 3D or 2D, if the approach works. In my example, both x and y are 2D, so dx dy has a total dimension of 4.